# Can you view the previous / current value in chrome devtool?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am wondering if there's an easy way to discover where I am and what the previous evaluated value is.

For example, in the codepen link, if I `Step Up` from `funcA`, I would land in `funcB` inside `console.log(funcA()*)`, where `*` is the current debugger position. Is there a way for me to tell that the frame that I just came out of returned a value of `"a"`?

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LBxwRP

PS: I am looking for a magic variable that the devtool assigns this value to, something like `$_` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only see the value in a debugger when it is stored/referenced by a variable. You can write your function call like below, and then you can see the value by watching `x`.

```
const funcB = () => {
  console.log(x = funcA());
}
```

The other option you have is to use Chrome inbuild support for `Return value` local scope variable, store it as global variable, and then access the same outside the scope. But again, it needs a manual intervention to opt for `Store as global variable` during debugging `funcA`.
[image] 

If you wanna do it programmtically, then assign a global variable with `funcA` result right before return.

 I understand what you are looking for and know the fact some Programming IDE/Engine supports this feature, but AFAIK chrome devtools is not there yet. 
`NOTE:`Its worth opening a feature request with  DevTools Community.

Comment: anyway to view values that are not stored by a variable?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: say that you only have `console.log(funcA())`, and you want to avoid adding an assignment for this so that I wont have to refresh and get back to the current state. I want to access the value right before the debugger cursor

Comment: I added other options you can use, but that's the closest DevTools support afaik.